# How to use grouped collection select to show multiple selection?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, grouped-collection-select

I'm using the following code to display a tree view selection box of categories:

```
grouped_collection_select(:logic, :logic_id, Logic.top_level, :child, :name, :id, :name, :include_blank => true)
```

How can I change it to allow multiple selection?

Also, is it possible to have it display checkboxes instead of a select box?

Comment: for displaying checkbox in select box http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/  i haven't tried with grouped_collection_select but i think it works checkout rails api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For displaying checkbox in select box [jquery multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) i haven't tried with `grouped_collection_select` but use
 select/select_tag with `option_groups_from_collection_for_select` it is more flexible.

Comment: to be more clear, this gives the optgroups with options. Now this needs to be wrapped inside a select tag like this `<%= select_tag "thename", option_groups_from_collection_for_select(arr, subarray, :title, :id, :name) `